# Update post meta in woocommerce order frontend

Tags: post-meta, woocommerce-offtopic, front-end

I will that the custome can update in the order the custom fileds (who was insert in the checkout page)

I have this code in the order-details.php Page but it show only the value in the input but he don't update with the new value

```
<?php
 global $post;


 if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) )
 {
 if( ! isset( $post ) ) {
 echo 'Error: Nichts ausgewählt';
 die();
 }
 else if( ! isset( $_POST['frontstrasse'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['frontstrasse'] ) ){
 echo 'Error: Strasse Not Set';
 die();
 }


 update_post_meta( $order->id, 'frontstrasse', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['Strasse'] ) );
 }


 $istrasse = get_post_meta($order->id, 'Strasse', true );


 echo print_r($istrasse);
 ?>
 <form method="post" action="">
 <input type='text' name='frontstrasse' value='<?php echo isset($istrasse) ? $istrasse : ''; ?>' />
 <input type='submit' value='save' />
 </form>
```

Comment: Your code is a mess. Please make sure code is readable and properly indended before posting it. Messy code is hard to debug, specially if almost all of it is off screen ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me. Sorry that the code is not good readable.

```
<?php
global $post;
$post = $order_id;
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){
  echo 'Update nicht';
} else  if ( ! empty( $_POST['frontstrasse'] ) ) {
  update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Strasse', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['frontstrasse'] ) );
  update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Haus-Nr', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['fronthausnr'] ) );
}
$istrasse = get_post_meta($order->id, 'Strasse', true );
$ihausnr = get_post_meta($order->id, 'Haus-Nr', true );
?>

<form method="post" action="">
<label>Strasse</label><input type='text' name='frontstrasse' value='<?php echo $istrasse ?>' />
<label>Haus-Nr</label><input type='text' name='fronthausnr' value='<?php echo  $ihausnr ?>' />
<input type='submit' value='save' name='frontsubmit' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this post looking for a solution for multiple resubmissions due to update_post_meta. Here's my solution after looking at these posts [wordpress get_post_meta check if multiple values set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994543/wordpress-get-post-meta-check-if-multiple-values-set) [Prevent processing data multiple times in Woocommerce thankyou hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091238/prevent-processing-data-multiple-times-in-woocommerce-thankyou-hook)  :

```
<?php
global $post;
$post = $order_id;
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){
  echo 'Update nicht';
} else 
 
 // Checking if this has already been done avoiding reload
if ( get_post_meta($order_id,"frontstrasse",true)!="" && get_post_meta($order_id,"fronthausnr",true)!="" {
return; // Exit if already processed
}

  update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Strasse', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['frontstrasse'] ) );
  update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Haus-Nr', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['fronthausnr'] ) );
}

$istrasse = get_post_meta($order->id, 'Strasse', true );
$ihausnr = get_post_meta($order->id, 'Haus-Nr', true );
?>

<form method="post" action="">
<label>Strasse</label><input type='text' name='frontstrasse' value='<?php echo $istrasse ?>' />
<label>Haus-Nr</label><input type='text' name='fronthausnr' value='<?php echo  $ihausnr ?>' />
<input type='submit' value='save' name='frontsubmit' />
</form>
```